# python pydub - wav works, mp3 doesn't

Tags: python, mp3, wav, pydub

Simple few lines, using pydub.

The wav line works, the mp3 line doesn't.

I do have ffmpeg installed (today), and included inthe path, and restarted PyCharm.

If I type ffmpeg in cmd window, all ok.

Not sure why one works an the other doesn't.

Any suggestions appreciated.

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment

sound1 = AudioSegment.from_wav("C:\\multimedia\\audio_temp\\1.wav")

sound2 = AudioSegment.from_mp3("C:\\multimedia\\audio_temp\\1.mp3")
...

Error back from mp3 line is:
...
  File "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/Audio1/audio_03.py", line 11, in <module>
    sound1 = AudioSegment.from_mp3("C:\\multimedia\\audio_temp\\1.mp3")
...
```

Comment: Is that the whole error message / traceback? Looks like just the beginning of it, can't really begin to guess what is wrong. Have you fixed it yet? Please provide the whole error message. Also, try another mp3.

Comment: Thanks cardamom - issue went away - see my own answer...

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end, I am not sure what the explanation is...

I am developing in PyCharm, and when I re-launched it today to get the whole error message, it notified me that there was a new version of PyCharm available, do I want to update?
Well, I said yes, of course.... and now everything works.
So I can only guess that some links / libraries were fixed along the way...
Makes sense - because the one line program worked for everyone else.

Thank you cardamom for your response :)

Regards

Garrett